# Two model in one UpdateView "Django"

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

my views :

```
from .models import Settings, SocialMediaSetting

class UpdateSocialMediaSetting(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = SocialMediaSetting
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = "staff/settings/social-media-settings-update.html"

class UpdateSettings(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Settings
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = "staff/settings/settings-update.html"
```

two different class in models without any relation, I want show both in one html and one form both models has just one object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need to ditch the UpdateView, but this way won't take long to implement

1. Use a TemplateView (at least you won't have to change your other mixin)
2. Create two ModelForms
3. override the get_context_data() to pass the forms to the template
4. when forms are submitted, override the post() method to save them yourself

mchesler613 wrote an awesome article explaining how to do this [here](https://github.com/mchesler613/django_adventures/blob/main/multi-modelforms_in_template.md).
(make sure to give him a star)